# How to get aTargets' array length?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using aoColumnDefs from the Datatable jQuery library. So I can use `"aTargets": [1, 2]` or such to define which column I want to change by this function. But my tables are dynamic, and I want to apply this function to all the columns except the first one. So how can I achieve this?
Sorry didn't post the code I used, here it is:

```
jQuery('.summary_tables').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
     {
         "aTargets": [1,2,-1],
         "bUseRendered": false,
         "fnRender": function ( o ) {
             return o.oSettings.fnFormatNumber( parseInt( o.aData[ o.iDataColumn ] ) );
         }
     }
 ]
});
```

Comment: please post what you have tried out

Answer (score 0):

Use the special value `"_all"` to target all columns, and follow it up with another line to override the setting for the first column. For example:

```
aoColumnDefs: [
    { aTargets: ["_all"], bSortable: false },
    { aTargets: [1], bSortable: true }
]
```

Comment: It is a good idea mate, but the thing is if you look at my code there, my function actually converts the value in each column into integer, and my first column is string, so after the first function, the first column got changed to `NaN`, and I can't convert it back to the original string.